# Why do YouTube videos start black?

Tags: firefox, youtube

I'm using the latest Firefox without Adobe Flash (so HTML5 videos) on YouTube. YouTube videos almost always start kind of black, parts of the image are barely visible.

Why do I have to wait a few seconds for the image to "stabilize" and be able to watch the video?

Is there something I can do to have the picture/video load instantly?

Here is what is happening in two pictures (timeline is wrong, I just clicked back to refresh the picture):

[image: first example] [image: second example]

Comment: Is this something happening only on YouTube or also an other video-platforms?

Comment: Hi, it is not limited to youtube. Same problem with dailymotion.com

Comment: I would like to have some more information. Could you please update your post with some system-specs: CPU(s)/GPU(s)/RAM/OS.

Comment: Core i5-3470 / ATI Radeon HD2400XT / 4GB RAM / Win 7 SP1

Comment: Please visit https://videos.cdn.mozilla.net/uploads/mozillaorg/ and test the three different video-container-formats. Is your behavior constant among mp4/ogv/webm? Or is this only happening on one type?

Comment: None of the videos have the bug on the page you linked. It may be linked to a page that is heavy on the CPU ?

Comment: On the pages where you encounter this bug, is the video also lagging at the beginning?

Comment: No video lag at all, the video starts right away and quite smoothly. It's only the picture that stays partially black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling [Hardware graphics acceleration](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/upgrade-graphics-drivers-use-hardware-acceleration) did the trick !

I lose the smooth scrolling but the videos seem to be working fine so far. I guess my video card isn't that well supported on Firefox.